# set newly created google sheet as the active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google sheets to import data into a mysql database. Each month a new sheet gets created for instance 06_2017. Is there a way to set the newly created sheet as active sheet or based on current month & year set that sheet as active. Instead of having to hard code

```
  var gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('06_2017'); 
  var gsheetname = sheet.getSheetName();
  var gdata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Comment: You could store the name of the sheet in PropertiesService and in your onOpen function use SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName() and get the name filename from scriptProperties. `var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); var sheetname = scriptProperties.getProperty('sheetname');`

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper have said, you can store the name of the newly created sheet in `UserProperties`, then place your code in `onOpen()` method of your script.

You can do it like this,

```
function onOpen(e)
{
  var prop = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var sheet_name = prop.getProperty(<NAME_OF_SHEET>);
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_name).activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to stick to the pattern 'MM_YYYY' for naming your sheets, the following code will always activate the sheet with the latest date. If your plan is to use different naming patterns in a single document, you need to refactor the code below to allow for this.

The onOpen() function is one of the so-called simple triggers in GAS, so every code inside this function will be executed when you open the document. The sort() method will sort array elements based on  given criteria. Since sort() doesn't know what criteria you'd like to use for sorting Sheet objects, you need to pass a comparator function to override the default one.

The comparator function parses sheet names and creates date objects by passing year and date (in that order) to the new Date() constructor. It then uses the result of date subtraction to sort the 'sheets' array in descending order, from the highest to the lowest value.

Finally, you take the first element of the sorted array (that would be the latest created sheet) and set it as the active sheet.

```
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets.sort(function(a,b) {

  var arr1 = a.getName().split("_");
  var arr2 = b.getName().split("_");

  return new Date(arr2[1], arr2[0]) - new Date(arr1[1], arr1[0]);

  });

if (sheets.length < 1) {

    return;
}


ss.setActiveSheet(sheets[0]);

}
```